# NavigationDrawer

Tags: android, kotlin, android-navigation-drawer

Нужно в приложение добавить меню(NavigationDrawer). Как я поняла это делается в  DrawerLayout, но у меня в активити уже есть ConstraintLayout. Подскажите как добавить пожалуйста

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
tools:viewBindingIgnore="true">

<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="280dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    android:id="@+id/container2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="280dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>
```

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

Comment: Вы пробовали поместить ваш ConstraintLayout в другой макет и потом создать макет где будет DrawerLayout и перед добавлением меню (NavigationView) поставить `<include>` и в нём указать ваш макет с помощью `layout="@layout/your_layout"`. Не забудьте также в вашем коде указать макет с вашим DrawerLayout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Android Studio есть целый шаблон для нового проекта: Navigation Drawer Activity.

Создайте новый проект используя этот шаблон, посмотрите, как там всё устроено, скопируйте себе.